# Get enum type and create list of that type , Get class type and create a list with that type with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to create a tool which invokes all of the functions within a library through reflection, for this i need to get the method information and parameters information. I was able to get these parameter info (with default values like if it is int =0, string = empty, float = 0, enum = getting a type values and 0 index value , if a parameter is of some type(isClass) then null.).

In this case i have one problem there are some functions which uses parameters `List<int> List<enum>, list<type>` now while creating a default values for these parameters is bit challenging for me, Can anyone help me on this.

1) List or any numerical list default values should be `List<int> defaultValueList = new List<int>(){0};`
2) For `list<Enum> enumDefault = new List<Enum>(){ Enum.Getvalues(0)}`
3)for List class_Default = get type , create instance , add it to one list after initializing( it should not be null that is the only objective that i have in this program.

Any help would be appreciated

Some of the code sample (Please note that NAMES defined above has nothing to do with the following example )

```
private object[] GetParameterInfoDefault(ParameterInfo[] pInfo)
        {
            int count = pInfo.Count();
            object[] objDefaultValues = new object[count] ;
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (ParameterInfo info in pInfo)
                {
                    objDefaultValues[i] = GetDefaultValurForTypes(info);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }


            return objDefaultValues;
        }
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to create default values here in this function for each parameter but for List i am not sure what has to be done i.e first part of the function

```
private object GetDefaultValurForTypes(ParameterInfo info)
        {
            object objectDefaultValue = new object();
        try
        {

            if (info.ParameterType.UnderlyingSystemType.Name.Equals("List`1"))
            {
                List<object> objList ; 
                Type[] tempTypes = info.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments();

                foreach (Type tempT in tempTypes)
                {

                    if (tempT.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(int))
                    {
                         objectDefaultValue = (tempT.UnderlyingSystemType.GetType()) ;

                        objectDefaultValue = 1;


                    }
                    else if (tempT.UnderlyingSystemType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        Array arr = tempT.UnderlyingSystemType.GetEnumValues();
                        objectDefaultValue = arr.GetValue(0);


                    }
                    else if (tempT.UnderlyingSystemType.IsClass)
                    {
                        objectDefaultValue =  Activator.CreateInstance(tempT);

                        //FieldInfo [] fldInfo = tempT.UnderlyingSystemType.GetFields();
                        //object [] fldInfoDefaultValues = new object[fldInfo.Count()];
                        //int i = 0;
                        //foreach (FieldInfo fldinf in fldInfo)
                        //{
                        //    fldInfoDefaultValues[i] = fldInfo.get
                        //}
                    }




                }

            }
            else if (info.ParameterType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
            {
                //object underlyingValue = Convert.ChangeType(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));

                Array arrayValue = info.ParameterType.GetEnumValues();
                objectDefaultValue = arrayValue.GetValue(0);

                //var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj); // this return TestOne or TestTwo

                //var enumValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(int)); // this return 3 or 4

            }
            //else if( info.ParameterType.BaseType == System
            //{

            //}
            //else   if (info.ParameterType.BaseType == typeof(int) || info.ParameterType.BaseType == typeof(float) || info.ParameterType.BaseType == typeof(double))
            //    objectDefaultValue = 0;
            else if (info.ParameterType == typeof(bool))
                objectDefaultValue = false;
            else if (info.ParameterType == typeof(int))
                objectDefaultValue = 1;
            else if (info.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                objectDefaultValue = string.Empty;
            //else if(info.ParameterType. == typeof(
            else
                objectDefaultValue = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        return objectDefaultValue;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
if(info.ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
     info.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    // create list
    IList objList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(info.ParameterType);

    // resolve T in List<T>
    Type type = info.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // avoid problems with List<Nullable<Something>>
    type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;

    // now apply any type-specific rules as per your existing code
    ..

    // add to list
    objList.Add(objectDefaultValue);
}
```